# How can I make an element overflow: auto when its parent is overflow: hidden?

Tags: css, overflow

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/x1svexwc/1/)

I'm trying to make it so that if the menu is greater than 100% height that I can scroll within the menu, but not in the body until the menu is closed.

When the menu is open I apply the following:

```
body.menu-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

And the menu styles:

```
.navbar .menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 150%; /* height greater than 100% */
  overflow: auto;
  top: 50px;
  left: -30%;
  background-color: DeepSkyBlue;
  transition: left 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `min-height` to `100%` and add `max-height` with `100%` to the menu:

```
.navbar .menu {
    position: fixed;
    width: 30%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    top: 50px;
    left: -30%;
    background-color: DeepSkyBlue;
    transition: left 0.2s ease-in-out;
 }
```

```js
$('.navbar .fa-bars').on('click', function() {
 $('body').toggleClass('menu-open');
 $('.navbar .menu').toggleClass('in');
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body.menu-open {
  overflow: hidden;
  
}

.navbar {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: royalblue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar .fa-bars {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar .menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  top: 50px;
  left: -30%;
  background-color: DeepSkyBlue;
  transition: left 0.2s ease-in-out;
}


.navbar .menu.in {
  left: 0;
}



.navbar .menu a {
  color: #fdfdfd;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="menu-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does adding `max-height` here do? Will the menu only go to 100% with this?

Comment: No. `max-height: 100%` enables scrollbar to appear because the menu overflows that 100% height of a `.menu`. See the snippet, please.

Comment: Gotcha! In my personal project I also had to add a `padding-bottom: 65px;` to the menu to get the last menu item to show at the bottom. I had it `position: fixed; top: 65px;` so it wasn't showing at first.

Comment: Congratulations!